# Why do sites tend to use new windows for authentication instead of inserted dialogs/iframes?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, iframe, widget

I'm designing a widget which, when clicked upon in a third-party site, will require authentication (username/password) from our server. I tend to see most, if not all, sites that use widgets requiring authentication tend to use a pop-up window rather than an in-page dialog box (such as using an inserted iframe), and I was wondering why this is the case. Are there actual security factors that distinguish an inserted iframe vs a popup window?

Comment: as a user I prefer to see in which page actually I'm entering my credentials. In that case I can at least trust the original service provider instead of a random third party website.

Comment: Looks like I found some good information over at Information Security:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/specific-risks-of-embedding-an-https-iframe-in-an-http-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, this is due to efficiency and security:
In many sites you authenticate yourself over SSL (HTTPS). However, supporting SSL connection has higher cost than normal HTTP.

Therefore, while you are a visitor in the site, you use HTTP. When you need to authenticate you do it from **separate window**, and usually over SSL- **where you can see the address line (and can verify that you actually use SSL, and check the certificate and such things)**.

It is common pattern that you can find also when visiting online shops, when you come to pay (only then you move from HTTP to HTTPS).

There is some problem with this approach (it would be safer to use SSL for the whole the connection), but the efficiency (that implies lower cost) usually wins. This is mainly true for not-very-big companies.